# Router link is being called all the time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink

I have the below code

```
 routerLink="{{onSelect(id)}}.
```

this method is being called all the time, and when i click to go to another tab this takes over, is there anyway in angular that this function will be called only when i `click` or `right-click(new Tab)`?
Thanks in advance!

My code is like this

```
HTML<a  routerLink="{{onSelect(prod?.key)}}">{{prod?.name}}</a>
Ts.
onSelect(prod){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.onSelectedEmmiter.emit(prod);
      }, 0);
}
SO i can not use (click) cause i need the option to open new tab in right click.
Using return [`/x/x/] or navigate work only the first time
```

Comment: Why wont you just call `(click)="onSelect(id)"` on your tabs?

Comment: i need the option to open the new tab with right click.

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong . I should be `(click)="onSelect(id)"` (assuming that `onSelect` is supposed to respond to used click). Besides that, answer to WHY it is called all the time:

This is because that particular binding is evaluated every time on the change detection cycle. Such cycle is started on every mouse/keyboard event as async task completion.

Comment: i need the option to open the new tab